# Uninstalling MAMP PRO

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I have been using MAMP PRO successfully for over a year.  Recently, when I attempted to start MAMP PRO,  it would not start.  I attempted to "restore" and that did not work.  Appsolute tech support suggested to uninstall and install the new version.  The MAMP PRO uninstall program did not work.  I get the "privileged action failed" error message.  I found this solution on "stackoverflow"

1. Delete the appsolute directory from /Library/Application Support , which contains configuration
       files that are created upon MAMP Pro installation
2. Delete the file hosts.mamp.bak in /etc, which is the MAMP hosts backup file
3. Delete the MAMP directory from /Applications/MAMP
4. Open the MAMP Pro Uninstaller, check all five options, and click to uninstall

I followed these instructions except I did not find "hosts.mamp.bak in the /etc folder...the folder was empty (I have since gone back to look again and I can't find the etc folder!).  Anyway, I am still unable to run the MAMP PRO uninstaller.  I am reluctant to try to install the newest version until this issue is resolved.  Any suggestions?  I am running OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: Hmmm...I am guessing at this time there is not a solution.  Is it time to switch to something like Desktop Server?

Comment: Okay...for any interested party, I ended up using the following link provided by Appsolute....http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/older-versions/  The older version is 2.2.  I installed it using my original registration number and re-established my database. Everything seems to be working again.

Answer (score 1):

Okay...for any interested party, I ended up using the following link provided by Appsolute....mamp.info/en/downloads/older-versions The older version is 2.2. I installed it using my original registration number and re-established my database. Everything seems to be working again.